# Why does my guava cache constantly overwrite items?

Tags: java, caching, guava

Hello everyone working with guava cache stumbled upon such a problem. I'm trying to implement storage in a CacheValue cache guava in which there are some fields. I made a guava cache based on LoadingCache and I can’t understand why when I add size () elements it is always 1?

My guava put method:

```
private LoadingCache<String, CacheValue> storage;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GuavaCache.class);

@Override
public void put(String key, Object value) {
    storage.put(key, (CacheValue) value);
    storage = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .maximumSize(MAX_SIZE)
            .removalListener(notification -> LOG.info("Element was remove: " + notification.getKey()))
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, CacheValue>() {
                @Override
                public CacheValue load(String key) {
                    return (CacheValue) value;
                }
            });
}
```

My main class:

```
   AbstractCustomCache gg = new GuavaCache();


    for (int i = 0; i < 102; i++) {
        gg.put("ab" + i, new CacheValue("ab" + i, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0));
    }

    gg.get("ab4");
    gg.get("ab2");
    gg.get("ab0");
```

My output:

```
CacheValue{value=ab0, creationDate=1549027075333, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab1, creationDate=1549027075333, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab2, creationDate=1549027075333, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab3, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab4, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab5, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab6, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab7, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab8, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
CacheValue{value=ab9, creationDate=1549027075334, frequency=0}  Size=  1
```

AbstractCustomCache:

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomCache implements CustomCache {
    static final int MAX_SIZE = 8;
    private Map<String, CacheValue> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Map<String, CacheValue> getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }
```

What is the problem? How it can be fixed?

Comment: Post the full `GuavaCache` class, or at the very least the complete `put` method on that class. Is it possible you're recreating the cache on every call to `GuavaCache#put()`?

Comment: I post the full put method

Comment: By the way the documentation about `size()` method states *Returns the approximate number of entries in this cache.*

Comment: My cache max size equals 8, but I added to cache 10 elements.

Comment: What is this AbstractCustomCache class? how storage is being used?

Comment: AbstractCustomCache provides get and put methods. Added this class to post

Comment: where are put/get methods in AbstractCustomCache

Comment: In CustomCache interface.

Comment: Can you please show the put method implementation. Its better if you post the whole code.

Comment: first method in this post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187744/discussion-between-ratish-bansal-and-mefisto-fell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `storage = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()` each time with put request.You should create that once.

```
storage = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .maximumSize(MAX_SIZE)
            .removalListener(notification -> LOG.info("Element was remove: " + notification.getKey()))
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, CacheValue>() {
                @Override
                public CacheValue load(String key) {
                    return (CacheValue) value;
                }
            });
```

Above should be called once while initializing the cache.
So what is actually happening is that with every put request you create new storage and add 'cacheValue' to it.Therefore at any point to time maximum entries is 1.